# Ubuntu Bionic - No Keyboard-Layout-Selector at Login-Screen

Tags: 18.04, keyboard-layout, login-screen, input-language

I have two computers running Ubuntu Bionic.

On one of them there is no language- /keyboard-layout-selector at the login screen.
What can I do to get it?
Is there any configuration file for the login-screen where this is to be set?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is your system a one user system, or are there multiple users?

Comment: The system where there is no language- /keyboard-selector has multiple users. I have another one with only one user and there there is a keyboard-selector at the login-screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the configuration file is `/etc/default/keyboard`. It's possible to edit it manually, if you know what you're doing, but you can also do it the GUI way.

Go to *Settings -> Region & Language*. There you see the keyboard layouts which you have easy access to once logged in to a session.

But - on your multiple users machine - if you click the *Login Screen* button at the top right of the *Region & Language* window, a new instance of the window shows up which refers to the login screen. There you can add those layouts which you want to have available on the login screen. If you set more than one layout there, you'll find an input source indicator on the login screen after next reboot.

This behavior is mentioned in the Ubuntu Desktop Guide in the note on this page:

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html

Personally I don't like the design in this respect. I find it non-intuitive, and you are not the first user who got stuck.

Comment: That is great! Thank you very much. And I think you are right. Although if you know it, you get there. But if not, it's hard to recognize that button at the top-right. If this would be inside the window as a separate item, I think people would find it easier.