# Wrong setting for my belgian keyboard at logon after upgrade to 22.04

Tags: upgrade, keyboard, 22.04

I upgraded my system from 20.04 to 22.04 yesterday.

I have one belgian keyboard (USB), defined as such.  When I try to logon, the keyboard is 'QWZERTY'.  Fortunately, I could 'see' and adapt my typing to enter my password to login.  After that, the keyboard reacts as "AZERTY", as it should.

I checked the keyboard settings.  Only one keyboard is defined ad is 'belgian' as it should.

What can I do to adjust the settings for the logon screen?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070757/ubuntu-bionic-no-keyboard-layout-selector-at-login-screen

Comment: @Esther that won't be applicable anymore for more recent versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally could make it work, thanks to the suggestion of @vanadium.
I edited the file `/etc/default/keyboard` to change the variant from `latin9` to `oss_latin9`.  I could find that the second variant is appropriate for belgian keyboard, although the original one seems incompatible with `XKBLAYOUT="be"`.  I found the full list here: https://gist.github.com/jatcwang/ae3b7019f219b8cdc6798329108c9aee

The result is

```
XKBLAYOUT="be"
BACKSPACE="guess"
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBVARIANT="oss_latin9"
XKBOPTIONS=""
```

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1: dpkg-reconfigure**

To update the default system keyboard layout, open a terminal and execute

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

In the screen "Keyboard layout", accept the default keyboard model as is, and select OK (press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to highlight `<OK>`then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

In the screen "Country of origin for the keyboard", select "Belgian", then select `<OK>`.

In the screen "Keyboard layout", select the desired variation.

In the "Key to function as AltGr" and following screens, keep "The default for the keyboard layout" selected, until the application quits and writes the changes.

The configuration is written in `/etc/default/keyboard`. The change will take effect on the next restart.

**Option 2: editing `/etc/default/keyboard`**

Instead, you may edit `/etc/default/keyboard` by hand. In your desktop session, you can learn about the current settings with either of the commands `setxkbmap -query` or `localectl status` and then substitute these values in `/etc/default/keyboard`.

Comment: Thank you but it does not change anything. The most surprising fact is the difference between login screen (wrong keyboard) and everything after (correct keyboard).  Looks like a bug but it surprises me that nobody would have noticed.

Comment: I answered my question as I found how to solve it.

Comment: You are right. I did it.