# Ubuntu 22.04 - No French (Belgian) keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I don't find the right keyboard in 22.04
French(AZERTY) but Belgian version - which is quite common here and was available in previous versions of Ubuntu.
Thanks!
Michel
[French Belgian AZERTY keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2J1j.png)

Where to find a French Belgian AZERTY keyboard that works in Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: this is a Q&A site not a discussion forum. What is your question?

Comment: Can you please edit the question to post screenshots of what you got in 22.04, and what you are expecting? Are you referring to the mapping of a physical keyboard, or some on-screen-keyboard

Comment: It sounds to me like the question is: Where to find a French Belgian AZERTY keyboard that works in Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: That keyboard is not available when performing the setup of my workstation.  Simply!  You see a sample in the link I put in my question to see how it looks like.

Comment: Please have a look at this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1425841/wrong-setting-for-my-belgian-keyboard-at-logon-after-upgrade-to-22-04

Comment: OK thanks Marc!  I just did the setup and will see at the next boot.  But these "Belgian" keyboards are not visible when selecting the keyboard menu in the system settings module.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Ubuntu 22.04, however I found the keyboard. It is just really well hidden.

If you search for French or Belgium, you will not find it, however if you search for Dutch, you will see the Belgium keyboard there (it is the same keyboard for Flemish and French).

[image: Image of language Belgium found in settings]